# Download g++ for Red Hat release 5.4

Tags: g++

My Linux machine has the following definition:

- RHEL 5.4
- Kernel release.2.6.18

but I don’t have the g++ command. (I need to write c++ programs under Linux)

For example:

```
 [root@linux /etc]# g++
 -bash: g++: command not found
```

I also tried the following:

```
 yum install gcc
 loaded plugins: security
 Setting up Install Process
 No package g++ available.
 Nothing to do
```

My question: How do I install/download the g++ command? From where can I get g++?

I have the gcc command but this is only for C programs, not C++.

```
  [root@linux /]# which gcc
  /usr/bin/gcc
```

From man page I see: (I'm not sure if gcc also compiles C++)

```
  [root@linux /]# man gcc
  GCC(1)                                GNU                               GCC(1)

  NAME
  gcc - GNU project C and C++ compiler
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the `gcc-c++` package.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the package which actually includes `g++`:

```
$ type g++
g++ is /usr/bin/g++
$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/g++
gcc-c++-3.4.6-11.el4_8.1
```

so, assuming you are connected to the internet, you can do this with yum:

```
$ sudo yum install gcc-c++
```

that will automatically install g++ and any other missing dependencies.